# How to change the value of VideoOutputTechnology of WmiMonitorConnectionParams?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10, wmi

I'm querying WmiMonitorConnectionParams:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorConnectionParams"))
using (var results = searcher.Get())
```

The problem is that the VideoOutputTechnology of WMI class WmiMonitorConnectionParams return me a certain value, i want to change this value in something else, but seems like there no way to do it.
First of all this proprieties is read only, so seems like it cannot be changed normally trought code:

```
foreach (var connection in results.Cast<ManagementObject>())
{
     connection["VideoOutputTechnology"] = 2147483648U;
     connection.Put(); // this cause an exception because the propriety it's read only
}
```

so i had an idea, i navigated and the modified the System.Management.dll using dnSpy, so that ManagementObject would not check anymore if the value i'm trying to momdify it's readonly, this lead me to a strange behaviour, in fact now i'm able to save the change to the ManagementObject, but this change are not persistent, and as soon i exit the foreach loop everything return as it was before. (i think that is because the connection variable is just a copy and doesn't direcly point to the ManagementObjectCollection, and by modifying it i'm not changing the collection).

So my question is if there is a way to somehow create a ManagementObjectCollection from a ManagementObject, or if there is a way to modify this wmi propriety of this class in the system, maybe via registry, or maybe in my c# code trought reflection or unsafe c#.